# Find and delete content with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, django, regex, beautifulsoup, django-queryset

I have blog text (application in django) where I want to get rid of some content. I try to search for content using BeautifulSoup. I want to find and delete everything between wphimage tags. Below is my code. What doesn't work is the wphimage tag that appears when I display soup objects after running it, where I did write to obj.text

my code

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article = Blogposts.objects.all()
        for obj in article:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(obj.text, 'html.parser')
            for i in soup.find_all('wphimage'):
                obj.text = str(i.replace_with(''))
                obj.save()
```

content of blog post

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

<wphimage data="{'FileId':6182,'Copyright':'John Smith','Alignment':'left','ZoomDisabled':false,'ImageOnly':false,'AlternativeText':'John Smith','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong','tabid':0,'moduleid':0}">
    <span style="display:block; float:left;" class="DIV_imageWrapper">
        <a data-lightview-title="Adela Frasineanu" data-lightview-caption="" class="lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG">
                    <img src="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" alt="John Smith">
                </a> 
               <a href="javascript:;">≡ <span>John Smith</span></a>
               <a class="A_zoom lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" data-lightview-title="John Smith" data-lightview-caption="">+ </a>
    </span>
</wphimage>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

and my goal is:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for getting first text `previousSibling` and last text `nextSibling`. You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

<wphimage data="{'FileId':6182,'Copyright':'John Smith','Alignment':'left','ZoomDisabled':false,'ImageOnly':false,'AlternativeText':'John Smith','ImageVersion':'conductorportraitlong','tabid':0,'moduleid':0}">
    <span style="display:block; float:left;" class="DIV_imageWrapper">
        <a data-lightview-title="Adela Frasineanu" data-lightview-caption="" class="lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG">
                    <img src="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" alt="John Smith">
                </a> 
               <a href="javascript:;">≡ <span>John Smith</span></a>
               <a class="A_zoom lightview" href="//example.com/static/images/image.JPG" data-lightview-title="John Smith" data-lightview-caption="">+ </a>
    </span>
</wphimage>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

first_text = soup.find("wphimage").previousSibling 
last_text = soup.find("wphimage").nextSibling

print(first_text.strip())
print(last_text.strip())
```

Output will be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```